# Facebook oauth login and Facebook notifications icon

Tags: facebook, user-interface, facebook-oauth

Need help to  create  icons  in 2 areas  for  Facebook.

```
 Here  are 2 screen  shots of icons  I need to  change

   1.in Facebook Oauth  popup

   http://goo.gl/7KiHwv![oauth  image][1]

  2.  by a notification in Facebook notifications

 http://goo.gl/QTxkfz
```

I tried   already  to  change  16x16 icon  in  app  details  in the developer.facebook.com  which  did  nothing.

Comment: Change the 1024x1024 logo

Comment: please add the images to the post, it'd help others

Comment: I need a level 10 to add images.

Comment: WizKid- thanks-- that was  it